# Crear un boton que cada vez que sea clickeado borre un párrafo de la página, empezando desde el último al primero JS

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito crear un botón que cada vez que sea clickeado borre un párrafo de la página, empezando desde el último al primero, pero la solución que cree primero me borra de a dos luego de a uno y por ultimo, el ultimo párrafo que me queda. No puedo encontrar la solución para que borre del ultimo al primero en el HTML. Se agradece la ayuda! Dejo lo que tengo:

```
var dom = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var parrafos = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

document.querySelector(".btn-deleteParagraph").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  for (let i = 0; i < parrafos.length; i++) {
    
    dom.removeChild(parrafos[i]);
  }
    
     
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes recoger los párrafos en una variable dentro del evento onclick, pues así se actualizará la colección de elementos que recoge en cada evento.

Luego, simplemente tienes que borrar el último de la colección:

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-deleteParagraph").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const parrafos = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    if (!!parrafos.length) parrafos[parrafos.length - 1].remove();
});
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>

<br><br>

<button class="btn-deleteParagraph">delete last one</button>
```

Con el `if` nos encargamos de que no haya error en la consola en caso de no haber más párrafos que eliminar.